# why is the code working for unsigned int but not for long long int

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-programming

This is from a dp question and the logic seems to work for unsigned int but shows the following error when using long long int even though long long int is much bigger than unsigned int.

Error: `signed integer overflow: 83700400893462717 + 9207044098280898870 cannot be represented in type 'long long'`

What is interesting is than the code works fine even for unsigned long long int.

```
int numDistinct(string s, string t) {
        int n = t.length() , m = s.length();
        vector<vector<unsigned long long int>> dp(t.size() + 1, vector<unsigned long long int>(s.size() + 1));
        dp[n][m] = (long long int)1;
        for(int i=n ; i>=0 ; i--){
            for(int j=m-1 ; j>=0 ; j--){
                if(i == n){
                    dp[i][j] = (long long int)1;
                }else if(t[i] == s[j]){
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i+1][j+1] + dp[i][j+1];
                }else{
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i][j+1];
                }
            }
        }
        
        return dp[0][0];
        
    }
```

This question is from leetcode code called Distinct Subsequences

https://leetcode.com/problems/distinct-subsequences/

Comment: For unsigned integers there is no overflow.:)

Comment: letcoode puts you in some weird environment. For testing and debugging you better use your own compiler. Probably the issue in the code with signed integer is present in the code with the unsigned integer as well. You just don't notice it because unsigned integers don't overflow.

Comment: Take the modulo of 1e9+3 at the end so as to avoid overflow

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments unsigned numbers can't overflow, but instead wrap around using the properties of modulo operation.

For instance, when unsigned int is 32 bits, then the result would be: `(a + b) mod 2^32`.